# Why the oracle databse is so unsafe? about "connect as" without a password

Tags: oracle

I start a sqlplus session, and enter "connect / as sysdba". just it. then the oracle let me login, without any password and user information.

so, is this just a XE edition's feature. or all oracle version let me login without a password.

by the way, what the "connect / as sysbda" means.

I can understand this "connect user/password@db-sid". but it doesn't follow this pattern. the databse don't has a sysdba user, so what's the command mean?

Comment: Refer Oracle documentation.

Comment: You can only do that if the operating system user you are using is either the one that installed oracle or part of the dba (or ora_dba) user group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle Forum Post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2196510?tstart=0)

> -- sqlplus "/as sysdba" it mean is you use OS authorization and your user must member of dba(ORA_DBA) OS group,else operation will fail.
>
> -- sqlplus sys/pass@sid as sysdba it mean is you use passwordfile authorization .And in this case you need properly configure this file
>   also need set remote_login_passwordfile= EXCLUSIVE or SHARED.